# how don't create .class java when I save my project

Tags: java, eclipse, class, visual-studio-code

I develop a Processing Library for Processing from many years, but since yesterday when I save my project with `VSCode`or `Eclipse` there are `file.class` created automatically in src folder at same level of `file.java` for each class of my code. After, it's very hard to navigate between the files. I don't find why it's happen, now and how disabled this automatic creation of `file.class`.
Below two screenshots to explain my problem.

Before:
[image]

After saved:
[image]

Comment: .class files are .java files compiled. To generate the .class files you have to compile your project.

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo but the problem, it's not when I compile my project the file.class appear, but the files appear when I do a save. Is it possible that my file changes location when I save my project?

Comment: When you save the file where? Notepad doesn't do that. Eclipse uses different folders (src/ vs bin/) by default for that.

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo just save, I don't specify the path. It's a regular save.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You give me a good idea, I checked the folder bin and my folder src. I found in the src one, a same file .classpath .idea .project. I remove it And know the file.class don't come back. Thx

Comment: Eclipse *can* be configured to use the same folder for source and class files (generally a bad idea), but the right "fix" is to change the output folder. (Project -> Build Settings afaik)

Comment: @JialeDu Yes I can, but I don't know how change the status

Comment: If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this setting in workspace *settings.json*

> A relative path to the workspace where stores the compiled output. Only effective in the WORKSPACE scope. The setting will NOT affect Maven or Gradle project.

```json
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
```